# Magento 2 : How to get Module images and css files

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created one module but module images and css not accessible from web folder. its access only one time. second time not accessible.

```
http://localhost/mage2ex/pub/static/frontend/_view/en_US/NS_Module/images/defaultbg.jpg
```

We have try `$block->getViewFileUrl()` and `$this->getViewFileUrl()` but no luck with this.

I don't know why added `_view` in `/mage2ex/pub/static/frontend/_view/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution using parameter with `$block->getViewFileUrl();`

```
echo $block->getViewFileUrl('NS_Module::js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js', array(
    'area'  => 'frontend',
    'theme' => 'Magento/luma'
));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can access images directly in your custom Module images e.g `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/images/my_image.jpg` can be accessed in css as follow:

```
background-image: url('@{baseDir}Vendor_Module/images/my_image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

After created module when you apply commands and run your website your css and js will be loaded first time and it will display from cache folder like

```
pub/static/frontend/...
```

so your frontend will execute fast